# Reversing vector's elements by their iterators

Tags: c++, copy

I tried to write the following function:

```
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator v_itt;

 void reverse(v_itt first, v_itt second)
 {
         std::cout << "first = " << *first << ", second = " << *second << std::endl;
         int *temp = &*first;
         *second = *first;
         *first = *temp;
         std::cout << "After reversing: first = " << *first << ", second = " << *second << std::endl;
 }
```

But when I tried to call it I got the following output:

```
first = 322, second = 12
After reversing: first = 322, second = 322
```

I thought, when we're initializing a pointer with another pointer, in the initialized pointer we simply get a copy of the value. Isn't that true?

Comment: Why not use [`std::reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)

Comment: @101010 I just don't understand the behavior.

Comment: When you initialize a pointer with another pointer, they now point to the same value, the *address* is copied, not the pointed-to-value.

Comment: Reversing normally takes a sequence and reverses the elements in that sequence. Your function (if it were implemented correctly) simply swaps the contents of two iterators (a la `std::iter_swap`).

Comment: Could you accept one of these answers?

Answer (score 4):

To swap elements you should do this:

```
temp = first
first = second // Here you have "second = first". It's the other way around!
second = temp
```

You have made a mistake at the second step, which results in your `reverse` operation giving `first` for both. The key idea is: you store a value (`first`) to temp, then with the following operation you can overwrite **that** value (`first`) because you won't lose it.

Comment: Or, use [std::swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) for slightly better readability.

Answer (score 2):

`int *temp = &*first;` why are you using pointer, you should store the value that `first` points to for swaping. When you initialize a pointer with another pointer, you get the copy of that pointer, not the value that pointer points to.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code preserves an integer in a redundant form of syntax:

```
int *temp = &*first;
```

Instead of preserving the pointer to first, simply preserve the value that first is pointing to:

```
int temp = *first;
```

Now, since you preserved the pointee of first, you can modify the pointer:

```
*first = *second;
```

Finally, use the preserved value to change the pointee of second:

```
*second = temp;
```